# Write stream to console or file based on user choice

Tags: c#, filestream

```
abstract class Car
{
    string Name;
    //some other fields

    abstract public void Details(Stream stream);
}

class Maruti : Car
{
    int x;
    //some other fields

    public override void Details(Stream stream)
    {
         // to do
    }
}

class Mercedes : Car
{
    int y;
    //some other fields
    public override void Details(Stream stream)
    {
         // to do
    }
}
```

I have to write the **Details** method such that if stream is console stream, then the output is displayed on console, and if the stream is file stream, then the output is written in a file.

Following is the way I achieved it :

```
public override void Details(Stream stream)
{
    string details = "Name : " + this.Name + Environment.NewLine ;
    if (stream is FileStream)
    {
        TextWriter tmp = Console.Out;
        StreamWriter sw2 = new StreamWriter(stream);
        Console.SetOut(sw2);
        Console.WriteLine(details);
        Console.SetOut(tmp);
        sw2.Close();
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine(details);
    }
}
```

I used the above method in both my derived classes with some modifications. Is there any better way to do?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to replace the whole body of `Details` with this:

```
    string details = "Name : " + this.Name;
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(stream);
    sw.WriteLine(details);
    sw.WriteLine();
```

Depending on if you want to further use the passed stream after writing the `details` string to it, you might want to also add the command:

```
    sw.Close();
```

Explanation: A `StreamWriter` is derived from a `TextWriter`... and `Console.Out`'s type is `TextWriter`. So you don't have to replace the console output with your temporary stream writer but can use it directly to write your stuff.

Also note that while you added `Environment.NewLine` to your `details` string, you should rely on the stream's own newline character which might be different from the environment's one. If you really want to have two newlines, you should go with two calls to `WriteLine` as demonstrated in my example above.

Comment: Even better to change to `Details(TextWriter writer)`.

Comment: Yes, if the class structure allows such a modification.

Comment: It doesn't look like something that is burried in multi-party specifications.

Answer (score 1):

This seems very wrong.

If you want to write to the Console, you should just pass to `Details()` the stream returned from [`Console.Out`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.out%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), then just always write to the stream in the implementation of `Details()`.

So you could call it like this:

```
myCar.Details(Console.Out);
```